# On the pinto bean plant's seed leaves, there are tan spots with gray ringed around the edges. Does that mean the seed leaves are going to fall off?

Tags: leaves, beans

1. The pinto bean plants are around 2-3 months old.
2. I sprayed them once or twice with water every day because it was really hot.
3. I didn't use sterilized soil for any of them.
4. I placed them into tiny pots, and I placed the pots on paper towels so that when I watered them, the excess water wouldn't run onto the windowsill.
5. The paper towels' edges are turning brown.
6. Some of the plants have been bent but not killed by my family's dog.
7. I put some potted green onions next to them.
8. They all have at least a set of three true leaves.

Comment: The seed leaves falling off is not a big deal once there are true leaves. Tiny pots and beans is not a good combination, though.

Answer (score 3):

If the beans are still in tiny pots and have 2 or 3 sets of true leaves, they need potting on into larger containers as soon as possible, or planting outdoors after hardening off if your weather is suitable currently. The seed leaves may or may not fall off, but the plants cannot grow on properly in tiny pots because their roots will be cramped and unable to expand to produce healthy plants. Adding photos showing these spots might be helpful for a more detailed response; it's currently not clear if you mean the spots are on all the leaves or not.